# How to do 2nd Spinner get selected , based on my 1st Spinner selection?

Tags: android

I am using Two Spinner in my App . 1st Spinner is array of STATE, 2nd Spinner is array of COUNTRY. Also i am using Spinner with key-value in easy way, i.e :

A - Spinner State:

i take an Array of states using as [KEY],

```
 []state = {"UP","MP",... ,"OUT SIDE INDIA"};
```

Also i take an another Array of states using as [value]

```
[]state_id = {"111","222",......"999"};
```

Both the above Array are identical in size.

B - Spinner Country:

i take an Array of country using as [KEY],

```
 []country = {"USA","UN",... ,"INDIA"};
```

Also i take an another Array of country using as [value]

```
[]country_id = {"01","01",......"200"};
```

Both the above Array are identical in size.

AND i am getting data [VALUE] of selected item of Spinner , like

```
    @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            String value = state_id[arg2];
        }
```

My Question is , How do i control 2nd Spinner [country] , if i select in 1st Spinner [state] ?

for example , i want to select UP , than 2nd Spinner should be auto select on INDIA as disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a checque on item selected in first spinner and then according to item selected in 1st spinner set value in second spinner...
eg.spinner.setselection(2);

check will be like

```
if(spinner1.getselecteditem==1)
     {


          spineer2.setselection(2);

       }
```